Does the object's motion trajectory have to be along the inclined plane?
let’s say we have a frictionless inclined plane The angle between it and the frictionless Horizontal desktop is “$θ$”.
And we have a very small object that can be considered as a mass point which has a mass of “$m$”.
The mass of the inclined plane is “$M$”
Gravity exists and free fall acceleration is “$g$”
Now the moment we gently place the object on the inclined plane(so its initial velocity is 0） , a computer controls the horizontal desktop to start moving upward with a constant acceleration which is “$a$” $a≠0$
There is no air resistance, and the object——inclined plane system is not subject to external forces in the horizontal direction.
The question is if we do this experiment in real life，wouldn't the object be temporarily separated from the inclined plane? Does the object's motion trajectory have to be along the inclined plane? If it does ，please give the reason because I can’t see any.

Why do you think such a separation should occur? Suppose $a=0$ and the desktop doesn't move at all. In that case do you expect separation? If not, consider that taking $a>0$ is effectively equivalent to making gravity stronger

Sorry, I forgot to clarify that a ≠0，now It has been changed  .The object——inclined plane system is not subject to external forces in the horizontal direction as it has shown. So according to the law of conservation of momentum，they will separate. At least in a very short time.

We are not talking about pseudo forces. The real forces acting on the object are gravity and the push from the inclined plane.

@Justaphysicsstudent how does conservation of momentum imply that the object seperates from the plane? This would require an external force lifting the object, which was ruled out by your setup.

@paulina,Once the object acquires velocity to the left, the inclined plane will acquire velocity to the right, and vice versa.

I guess that even if the inclined plane is fixed on the desktop, when θ or a is within a certain range, the object will still bounce off the inclined plane.

You've missed my point, I know you meant that $a>0$ (it can't be negative either if the system is moving upwards). The point is, I am claiming this is just setting gravity to a new constant $g'$ where $g'=g+a$. In the frame that movea upwards with the inclined plane, gravity is stronger, why would that cause a separation of the mass from the inclined plane?

Btw, if instead of writing "the moment we gently place the object..." you'd allow for some non zero duration to pass before activating the desktop, this may clarify better the scenario I think you are trying to get at

@Amit By that ，I mean the initial velocity of everything is 0.

The point I was making is that in the current setup the point mass never experienced a downward force of mg. From the beginning it is m(g+a)

@Amit One goes left, another goes right. Law of conservation of momentum predicts.

A separation implies the normal force between inclined plane and the mass vanishes, I think you need to explain how that happens in your analysis

@Amit According to Newton's first law, velocity requires no force to maintain.

@Justaphysicsstudent but the upwards velocity of the plane is not constant.

@Justaphysicsstudent I suggest drawing a free body diagram of the problem and trying to work out the equations of motion. If you do that and are still in difficulty, you can even post the FBD in your question and ask for further help. So far, it seems like you are arguing from intuition which can be misleading, as I tried to point out with my comments.

The normal force $N$ between the object and the inclined plane is such as to enforce the constraint that the object cannot interpenetrate into the plane (due to molecular forces).
But also $N \ge 0$ or else the object will separate as a negative force would be required to keep them together otherwise.
So you do the mathematical modeling of the system and depending on the value of resulting normal force $N$ it will either stick to the plane, or separate.
By intuition, if the table is accelerated downwards with more than $m g \cos \theta$ then the object would separate. Please check this mathematically before going with it.

Kinematics
We decompose the motion of the object into two velocity components, $v$ along the inclined plane, and $u$ away from the plane.
The velocity vector of the object in the inertial frame is a function of these two components:
$$ \dot{x} = v \cos \theta - u \sin \theta \\
\dot{y} = v \sin \theta + u \cos \theta $$
The the derivative give us the acceleration vector
$$ \ddot{x} = \dot{v} \cos \theta - \dot{u} \sin \theta \\
\ddot{y} = \dot{v} \sin \theta + \dot{u} \cos \theta $$
Prescribed Motion
Given that we specify $a$ the prescribed vertical acceleration of the ramp, with $\ddot{y} = a$, the acceleration vector is really a function of a single unknown component, the in-plane value $\dot{v}$.
$$ \ddot{x} = \frac{ \dot{v} - a \sin \theta}{\cos \theta} \\
\ddot{y} = a $$
Equations of motion
The equation of motion of the object are
$$ \mbox{-} N \cos \theta = m \ddot{x} \\
N \sin \theta - m g = m \ddot{y} $$
where $N$ is the normal force between the ramp and the object
The solution
Solve the equations of motion for $N$ and the slip acceleration $\dot{v}$
$$ N = \frac{m (a + g )}{\cos \theta} \\
\dot{v} = -g \sin \theta $$
Solution limits
The problem changes once the object separates, which happens when $N < 0$, or
$$ a < \mbox{-} g$$

With regards to your last point, it seems to me that a downward acceleration $a$ implies the normal force applied by the inclined plane on the mass changes from $mg\cos\theta$ upwards to $m(g-a)\cos\theta$ upwards. Therefore it seems that the condition for a vanishing normal force is $a \geq g$ (**upwards here means in the direction perpendicular to the plane)

@Amit - Yes, the equation for $N$ is $$ N = \frac{ m (a+g)}{\cos \theta} $$

I think not but maybe I'm wrong. let's take the case $\theta=60^o$ so if your expression is correct we'll have twice the normal force than the case $\theta=0^o$... does it make sense that a more slanted incline increases the normal force?

Think about it, you use a sharp knife to cut, not a dull one.
